# Error: Cannot find module '@utils' after compile Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I am currently create a express-typescript boilerplate for myself and this is what i didnt expect because i build this boilerplate base on another boilerplate is express-typescript-starter

```
> Error: Cannot find module '@utils'
> Require stack:
> C:\Users\xflas\OneDrive\Documents\Personal Projects\Boilerplate\my-boilerplate\dist\app.js
> C:\Users\xflas\OneDrive\Documents\Personal Projects\Boilerplate\my-boilerplate\dist\server.js
```

And this is my tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2017",
        "lib": [
            "es2017",
            "esnext.asynciterable"
        ],
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "pretty": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "allowJs": true,
        "noEmit": false,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "baseUrl": "src",
        "paths": {
            "@/*": [
                "*"
            ],
            "@config": [
                "config"
            ],
            "@controllers": [
                "controllers"
            ],
            "@dtos": [
                "models/dtos"
            ],
            "@exceptions": [
                "exceptions"
            ],
            "@interfaces": [
                "interfaces"
            ],
            "@middlewares": [
                "middlewares"
            ],
            "@models": [
                "models"
            ],
            "@routes": [
                "routes"
            ],
            "@services": [
                "services"
            ],
            "@utils": [
                "utils"
            ]
        }
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts",
        "src/**/*.json",
        ".env"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "src/http",
        "src/logs",
        "src/tests"
    ]
}
```

My app.ts

```
import express from 'express';
import hpp from 'hpp';
import helmet from 'helmet';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import cors from 'cors';
import swaggerJSDoc from 'swagger-jsdoc';
import swaggerUi from 'swagger-ui-express';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import { IRoute } from '@interfaces';
import { logger, stream } from '@utils';
import { errorMiddleware } from '@middlewares';
import { Database } from '@models';
import config from '@config';

export default class App {
  public app: express.Application;
  public env: string;
  public port: string | number;

  constructor(routes: IRoute[]) {
    this.app = express();
    this.env = config.NODE_ENV || 'development';
    this.port = config.SERVER.PORT || 8080;

    this.connectToDatabase();
    this.initializeMiddlewares();
    this.initializeRoutes(routes);
    this.initializeSwagger();
    this.initializeErrorHandling();
  }

  private connectToDatabase() {
    Database.sequelize.sync({ force: false });
  }

  public listen() {
    this.app.listen(this.port, () => {
      logger.info(`=================================`);
      logger.info(`======= ENV: ${this.env} =======`);
      logger.info(` App listening on the port ${this.port}`);
      logger.info(`=================================`);
    });
  }

  public getServer() {
    return this.app;
  }

  private initializeMiddlewares() {
    this.app.use(morgan(config.LOG_FORMAT, { stream }));
    this.app.use(cors({ origin: config.ORIGIN, credentials: config.CREDENTIALS }));
    this.app.use(hpp());
    this.app.use(helmet());
    this.app.use(express.json());
    this.app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    this.app.use(cookieParser());
  }

  private initializeRoutes(routes: IRoute[]) {
    routes.forEach(route => {
      this.app.use('/', route.router);
    });
  }

  private initializeSwagger() {
    const options = {
      definition: {
        openapi: '3.0.0',
        info: {
          title: 'Express API for Boilerplate',
          version: '1.0.0',
          description: 'Express Boilerplate API Docs',
        },
      },
      apis: ['swagger.yaml'],
    };
    const specs = swaggerJSDoc(options);
    this.app.use('/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(specs));
  }

  private initializeErrorHandling() {
    this.app.use(errorMiddleware);
  }
}
```

Thank you so much

I tried to delete the node_modules and try to edit the tsconfig.json with types: ["node"] but it not working

Comment: I can run it with nodemon on app.ts file but after it compile, I run the app.js occur the error

Comment: Shouldn't paths in tsconfig.json be prepended with `src/`? Like "src/controllers" ?

Comment: Can you be more detail :( , im new to typescript

Comment: I meant `   "@controllers": [
                "src/controllers"
            ],`

Comment: I solve it by @* in path of tsconfig.json